# Solr query with space is not proper work

Tags: solr

I am searching data with space keyword like

> "Great Grand"

but all results from solr are messed up like some documents included Great and some documents included Grand. I do not want Great and Grand keyword. I only want that included "Great Grand" keyword in document.

In schema, I make it Tokenizer like this

```
<analyzer type="index">
  <tokenizer class="solr.StandardTokenizerFactory"/>
</analyzer>
<analyzer type="query">
  <tokenizer class="solr.KeywordTokenizerFactory"/>
</analyzer>
```

how can I change in solr to search for combination keyword search?

Comment: Are you talking about a _single value_ of `Great Grand`, or `Great Grand` somewhere in the document (but where `Grand` follows `Great`)? Is case important? I.e. is `Great Grand` and `great grand` different values and should not give a hit if matched?

Comment: I didn't say I need case sensitive. Let say you wanna look for IPad Air. In that case, you only want that document is taking about IPad Air.. not IPad , not air..

Answer (score 0):

You need to change the index type analyzer for your field.

It looks like you are looking for exact match.

keep both, index and query type `tokenizer` as `class="solr.KeywordTokenizerFactory"`.

Re-index the data and test the same.

Answer (score 0):

To change how phrase matching behaves with the edismax (and dismax) handlers (use defType=edismax to get edismax handling if you're not already doing that), you can change the values of `qs` ([query slop](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/solr/The+DisMax+Query+Parser#TheDisMaxQueryParser-Theqs(QueryPhraseSlop)Parameter)):

> The qs parameter specifies the amount of slop permitted on phrase queries explicitly included in the user's query string with the `qf` parameter. As explained above, slop refers to the number of positions one token needs to be moved in relation to another token in order to match a phrase specified in a query.

So if you're searching for "iPad Air" (with quotes), the `qs` parameter tells Solr the distance you're allowing between `iPad` and `Air`.

You can also use `pf2`, `pf3` and their attached `ps` values to boost documents where the terms appear close to each other instead - the bonus being that a search for just `ipad air` without quotes will give better and more relevant results, as hits close to each other will receive a higher ranking, while still returning documents containing "the new ipad, named according to the new naming scheme, as Air" will still give hits, but documents containing iPad and Air after each other will give a better ranking.

Answer (score 0):

What's your default operator? It's the q.op in your query/solrconfig.xml or defaultOperator in your schema.